# How to replace special characters in NSString with unknown index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to replace some characters with unknown index like this(i need to replace this Ă,Ŏ,Ĭ,ă,ŏ,ĭ and my input nsstring can be anything):

```
(void)repairText:(NSString *)textToRepair{`
    NSString *pom = textToRepair;`
    int pomNum = [pom length];

    NSLog(@"Input nsstring: %@",pom);

    for (int a = 0; a<pomNum; a++) {
        NSString *pomChar, *pomChar2;

        pomChar = [pom substringFromIndex:a];
        pomChar2 = [pomChar substringToIndex:(1)];
            NSLog(@"Char to repair: %@",pomChar2);

        if ([pomChar2 isEqual: @"Ă"] || [pomChar2 isEqual:@"Ŏ"] || [pomChar2 isEqual:@"Ĭ"] || [pomChar2 isEqual:@"ă"] || [pomChar2 isEqual:@"ŏ"] || [pomChar2 isEqual:@"ĭ"]) {

            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"Ă"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong big a");
            }
            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"Ŏ"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong big o");
            }
            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"Ĭ"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong big i");
            }
            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"ă"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong small a");
            }
            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"ŏ"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong small o");
            }
            if ([pomChar2 isEqual:@"ĭ"]) {
                NSLog(@"Wrong small i");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Good");
        }
    }

    pom = [textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"•" withString:@" kulka "];
    pom = [textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¥" withString:@" jen "];
    pom = [textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"£" withString:@" libra "];
    pom = [textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@" euro "];

    [self synthesize:pom];
}
```

But I am having trouble with 'if'. If anyone know about this, please help in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *str=@"ĂdsdaĬsd";
str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ă" withString:@""];
str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ĭ" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

O/p :dsdasd

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` has functions to do that for you. `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` is the method you need.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3aallowLossyConversion%3a):

```
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding allowLossyConversion:(BOOL)flag
```

> If flag is YES and the receiver can’t be converted without losing some information, some characters may be removed or altered in conversion. For example, in converting a character from NSUnicodeStringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding, the character ‘Á’ becomes ‘A’, losing the accent.

Sample code:

```
NSString *str = @"á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ";

NSData *asciiStringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                     allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *finalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiStringData
                                    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

The final string will be : `a, e, i, o, u, u, n`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * textToRepair = @"Your String";
textToRepair =[textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"•" withString:@"kulka"];
textToRepair =[textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"¥" withString:@"jen"]
textToRepair =[textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"£" withString:@"libra"];
textToRepair =[textToRepair stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@"euro"];;
```

and now textToRepair is your output string with changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can used this:

```
NSString * myString = @"Hello,";
```

NSString * newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@xx",newString);

I hope this is used full to you.